# plot multiple spectrograms for chunks of values in a column vector and save them as .jpg dynamically

Tags: python-3.x

I tried Specgram function (matplotlib) to plot multiple Specgram for a column of values in (a loop) chunks of 5, then save it to a folder, but it only plots 1.

```
chunk_size= 5
lf = [128,129,130,140,120,128,125,135,138,130]
pd.DataFrame(lf)

for i in range(0, len(lf), chunk_size):
    chunk = lf[i:i+chunk_size]
    specgram(chunk, NFFT=1024, Fs=1024,noverlap = 0)
    print (chunk)
```